# When viewing a svelte component in VSCode, how to go to the parent file that imports this component

Tags: svelte

Say I'm working on `Foo.svelte` in VSCode. I don't know which parent component contains `<Foo />`, and I want to find out. How?

In react, I could use **Find Reference** because `Foo` is a function.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the direction you were going in.  I deleted my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Svelte extension has a built-in command with the label:

```
Svelte: Find Component References
```

Execute that via the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_command-palette) in the component file and it should show imports and use in markup.

If the component has a `<script>`, you can also place your cursor in the tag name and use the commands `Peek References`, `Go to References` and `References: Find All References`. (Added in v.107.11.0 of extension.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do: In the "Search" sidebar, type `import Foo`.